# Rails 5 Unpermitted Parameter Upon Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I'm working with two models `Submission` and `Tag`.  `Submission` `has_one :tag`.  In my controller I have set up my `submission_params` as follows:

```
params.require(:submission).permit(:domain, tag_attributes:[:tag_text, :notes])
```

However, I'm getting the error: `Unpermitted parameter: tag`

From my log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BEJZXOERC3cGSZFlAL91kRJgR+YFcHd6+yMYilDyu/NyN1YviwahKwrifAQfWMdu53/NYCnOVD4NHNXSZmPk7Q==", "submission"=>{"domain"=>"test", "tag"=>{"tag_text"=>"test tag", "notes"=>"test"}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Perhaps I'm just rusty and am overlooking something or does rails5 have a new trick to dealing with strong params?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `params.require(:submission).permit(:domain, { tag: [:tag_text, :notes] })`

Comment: `*_attributes` is the correct form because you are passing nested attributes to model

Comment: @mr_sudaca Thanks for the response; I got the error `AssociationTypeMismatch` when I tried that.

Comment: What about `params.require(:submission).permit(:domain, { tag_attributes: [[:tag_text, :notes]] })`

Comment: @mr_sudaca Nope, `unpermitted parameter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is

```
accepts_nested_attributes :tag
```

here is how you'd permit it:

```
# :_destroy is for being able to delete the nested tag
params
  .require(:submission)
  .permit(:domain, tag_attributes: %i(id submission_id tag_text notes _destroy))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `tag_attributes` param instead of `tag` - see you log output

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm afraid I don't follow; are you suggesting that I need to change how I'm nesting fields in my form?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would not get proper param name. I think these links you might find helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566901/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-do-nested-forms-with-a-has-one-relationship and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569774/strong-parameters-for-nested-has-one-association